# Python: String Manipulation

Tags: python, string

I am trying to `append` a character to a string after every three characters
For example if my string is `NYCLHRNYC` the result would be `NYC-LHR-NYC`
The length of the string is always a multiple of 3

I have written the following code:

```
x = raw_input("Enter the route")
print "Route: %s" %x
length = len(x)
print length
if length == 6:
    newx= x[0:3] +"-"+ x[3:6]
elif length == 9:
   newx= x[0:3] +"-"+ x[3:6] +"-"+ x[6:9]
elif length == 12: 
    newx= x[0:3] +"-"+ x[3:6] +"-"+ x[6:9] +"-"+ x[9:12]
elif length == 15: 
    newx= x[0:3] +"-"+ x[3:6] +"-"+ x[6:9] +"-"+ x[9:12]+"-"+ x[12:15]
elif length == 18: 
    newx= x[0:3] +"-"+ x[3:6] +"-"+ x[6:9] +"-"+ x[9:12]+"-"+ x[12:15]+"-"+ x[15:18]
elif length == 21: 
    newx= x[0:3] +"-"+ x[3:6] +"-"+ x[6:9] +"-"+ x[9:12]+"-"+ x[12:15]+"-"+ x[15:18]+"-"+ x[18:21]
print "After formattinng: %s" %newx
```

Now this is a very mechanical way of doing it. In most of the cases I wouldn't know the max length of the string.
Is there a better way of doing it with a `for loop` or something else?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: so write a method that formats your string (give the method the parameter of your length) and with a bit math you can get it work ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's very simple:

```
newx = "-".join(x[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(x), 3))
```

Comment: Wow its amazing to have this thing in just one line of code. Thank you so much. I thought I had to do this with a for loop.

Comment: Could also do this with re:  `re.sub('.{3}', '\g<0>-', x)`  This has the (possibly undesired) effect of adding a '-' after the last group of three characters, if the total number of characters is a multiple of 3 ...

Comment: @jfsturtz: That is definitely an undesired effect because the OP mentioned that the length of the string is always a multiple of 3, but one could always use `string.strip("-")`.

Comment: @jfsturtz: Excuse me for a late reply, but a recent upvote brought me back.  A negative look-ahead would solve that undesired effect: `re.sub('.{3}(?!$)', '\g<0>-', x)`